# how to configure less in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, less

I downloaded the plugin from http://www.normalesup.org/~simonet/soft/ow/eclipse-less.en.html.

and installed in on eclipse however when I try to compile the less to css I get this error

```
Cannot be launched because of an I/O exception
Cannot run program "lessc": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

can anyone whose successfully installed this guide me in the right direction ? Also xtext is installed already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a similar issue for the [lessc GitHub repo](https://github.com/vtst/ow): [issues/213](https://github.com/vtst/ow/issues/213)

> > I added a new launch configuration as follows:

```
LESS command: lessc (existing)
Compress the generated CSS file (existing)
Use this launch configuration as default
```

> Your have to change the "**LESS Command**".
>   Please filling your "`lessc`" physical path, just like "`C:\Users\[Yourname]\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc.cmd`"
>   (Windows 7, node.js standard installer)

That means you must indicate the full path of `lessc.cmd`

Comment: For windows users: Here is a nice tut how to install lessc http://www.thinkingmedia.ca/2014/01/how-to-install-less-css-compiler-on-windows-7-for-phpstorm-7-0/